# Actually generic length function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

`length` is generic on the input in that it accepts any `Foldable`.

`genericLength` is generic on the output in that it outputs any `Integral`.

Is there an actually fully generic function with type:

```
(Integral b, Foldable t) => t a -> b
```

Or even:

```
(Num b, Foldable t) => t a -> b
```

As even though length should only ever produce integer values, integers are also floats, so producing any number works just fine.

Currently I am just using:

```
foldl' (const (+ 1)) 0
```

I know one can be made fairly easily, but I also know that often the base functions are optimized in some way or another, so I was hoping there was an existing function for generically calculating `length`. If not my followup question is why? Specifically why doesn't `genericLength` accept a `Foldable`?

Comment: you can use `fromIntegral . length` instead of `foldl' ...`

Comment: @behzad.nouri I agree, especially on 64 bit systems that is more than enough.

Comment: `foldl'` is optimized exactly as much as you need. However, `fromIntegral . length` will often be faster because `Int` arithmetic is faster than, say, `Integer` arithmetic.

Comment: Good to know. Does anyone know why this isn't the default implementation for `genericLength`?

Comment: @semicolon, thanks to its unfortunate reference implementation, `genericLength` is only really good for lazy natural numbers implemented in one particular way. That terrible flaw is pasted over for `Int` and `Integer` using rewrite rules. However, the potential performance problems are sufficiently serious that most people have just learned not to use `genericLength`, ever. So generalizing it would generally be a waste of time.

Comment: @dfeuer Could that be fixed by changing the reference implementation to `fromIntegral . length`?

Comment: @semicolon, not really. That could break on 32-bit architectures, and would break any obscure code that relies on the current behavior (I'm told there's at least one program out there that relies on it). That said, it might be possible to convince the right people some day.

Comment: @dfeuer Some people have lists that are longer than 2^32? Because `genericLength` can only work on lists...

Comment: Why not? `length $ [1..10] ++ [1..(maxBound :: Word)]` shouldn't take too long if you use `-O2`.

Comment: @dfeuer Alright fair enough, well in that case why not have the reference implementation be `foldl' (\n _ -> n + 1) 0`, wouldn't that be ok, if a little slower than `fromIntegral . length`.

Comment: That will never work if the list is infinite. Can you see why the reference implementation can with the right `Num` instance?

Comment: By right do you mean custom? I can't think of one honestly, without some weird optimization rewrite rules and an `Infinity` value.

Comment: Use `data Nat = Z | S Nat`. Can you find five different ways to implement `+`? Can you see why some of these will make `genericLength` work for infinite lists?

Comment: Ah I see. So it would just be an infinite list of `S`? But I mean isn't that just basically a weird way of doing `\list -> const () <$> list` seeing as list is defined in a similar-ish way.

Comment: Would something like having `genericLength` with `foldr` and potential performance issues and rewrite rules, but then also having `genericLength'` with `foldl'` and good performance work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean this was pretty much answered in the comments. But just so this question is marked as answered the reason is basically that `genericLength` has terrible performance due to it supporting lazy natural numbers, and thus should pretty much be avoided. This performance issue is partially avoided via rewrite rules, but even with that it is still not a good function to use and thus it isn't worth it to attempt to generalize it further.